# Can delays be approximated by ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

I have a system (of first-order, homogeneous ODEs) which contains a time delay

$$b(t) = a(t-T).$$

Are there any standard methods for approximating $b$ by $\bar{b}$, where $\bar{b}$ derives from $a$ via a system of ODEs? I envision this system as a "black box" with inherent time delay $T$, rather than hard-coding the delay as in the original equation.

For example, we could try

$$\bar{b}^\prime(t) = k \left(a(t) -\bar{b}(t)\right)$$

where

$$k = \frac{2 \log 2}{T}$$

as a simple choice. If $a = a_0$ were constant, $\bar{b} \to a$ as $t \to \infty$, and moreover at $t = \frac12 T$, $\bar{b}(t) = \frac12 \left(b_0+a_0 \right)$: after half the delay, the system has moved half-way to the correct answer.

Are there more formal approximations available?

Answer (score 2):

You might try using a Taylor polynomial
$$ a(t-T) \approx \sum_{j=0}^d \frac{(-T)^j}{j!} a^{(j)}(t) $$